# How to view query in existing BIRT spreadsheet report

Tags: birt

How to view query in existing BIRT spreadsheet report in BIRT 11. Need to analyze the query to find the tables used in it.

Comment: do you only have the excel file that was generated by BIRT? You can always look at the XML of the rptdesign file.

Answer (score -2):

You will have `rptdesign` as `xml` configuration file for your report/spreadsheet.

You will find query in it enclosed in `[]` brackets.

Comment: there will be many things between brackets in any report design file. The only thing true is that the query is "somewhere" in the rptdesign file.